# Prev state is set to default when using dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two reducers, one with the name of **Month** and the other with **Loading**

```
export const Month = (state = '', action) =>
  action.type === 'selectedMonth' ? (state = action.payload) : '';
```

Second one,

```
export const isLoading = (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'setLoading':
      return !state;
    case 'removeLoading':
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I'm using **dispatch** inside the **useEffect** multiple times for the different actions. At first call i-e `dispatch(actions.setMonths())` works fine but when I recall the dispatch for the different action i-e `dispatch(actions.setLoading())` the store gets updated but the state of the month is set to the initial state.

dispatcher calls,

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch(actions.setLoading());
      const res = await getData('users');
      dispatch(actions.removeLoading());
    };

    //any code
    dispatch(actions.selectedMonth("argument"));

    fetchData();
  }, [months, dispatch]);
```

More Details,

[image: call dispatch(actions.selectedMonth("argument"))]

[image: call dispatch(actions.setLoading())]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Month` reducer returns `''` if the type of the action is not `selectedMonth`. So when the action is `setLoading` or `removeLoading`, the month gets setback to an empty string

change your `Month` reducer to

```
export const Month = (state = '', action) =>
  action.type === 'selectedMonth' ? action.payload : state;
```

Comment: yes, this is the issue. But I want to keep my previous state.